# Equivalent of c++ std::hash<string>() function in c#

Tags: c#, c++, hash, std

Is there an equivalent of c++ std::hash() function in C#?

Basically, I use std::hash function on collection of strings and store them in a table as the primary key. My teammate is using c# code to retrieve the entry using primary key. So also needs to use the exact same hash function for retrieval.

Is there some common hash function that we can use in both c++ and c#?

Comment: It's probably safer to use a well known hash function instead of a language specific one. For example, what would happen if the next version of C++ changed the way it worked internally?

Comment: It may be worthwhile pointing to documentation for that hash function, so we can at least see what it is meant to do.

Comment: Given that it looks like your hashes need to be unique (that is, you can't tolerate collisions), in lieu of any other requirements I'd go for a well-known cryptographic hash, e.g. SHA1.

Comment: @canton7 SHA1 collisions in the wild have been demonstrated a couple of years ago, SHA256 or SHA512 is the way to go today

Comment: @zaitsman My assumption is that nobody is *trying* to generate a collision - if this is the case, SHA1 should be just fine. If this needs to be cryptographically secure (rather than just resistant against accidental collisions) yes I agree, but that's not in the question.